# Interpreting a chain of m's and o's from Macaulay2

Tags: computer-science, computer-algebra-systems

> This has been crossed referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972736/interpreting-data-from-macaulay2) as well in case a software developer understands this language.

I am using Macaulay2 and does anyone know how to read the following?

**Example 1:**

-- [gb]{1}(6)mmmmmm{2}(2)mm{3}(2)mm{4}(1)o{5}(1)m{6}(2)oo

-- number of (nonminimal) gb elements = 11

-- number of monomials                = 59

-- ncalls = 1

-- nloop = 24

-- nsaved = 0

**Example 2:**

-- [gb]{1}(6)mmmmmm{2}(3)mmm{3}(2)mm{4}(4)mmmo{5}(6)mooooo{6}(4)oooo{7}(1)o

-- number of (nonminimal) gb elements = 15

-- number of monomials                = 94

-- ncalls = 11

-- nloop = 190

-- nsaved = 0

> I do not understand the chain of m's and o's and the curly bracket with a number in it, for example, {2}, and the round bracket (2). [Here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.4/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_gb__Trace.html) is what the chain of those symbols is supposed to mean, but I am not a computer programmer so it is somewhat difficult to interpret the above information.
>
> For example: do I read this 
>   $$
>  [gb]\{1\}(6)\mbox{mmmmmm}\{2\}(3)\mbox{mmm}\{3\}(2)\mbox{mm}\{4\}(4)\mbox{mmmo}\{5\}(6)\mbox{mooooo}\{6\}(4)\mbox{oooo}\{7\}(1)\mbox{o}
> $$
>   from left to right, or should we interpret each set $$\{1\}(6)\mbox{mmmmmm}$$ or $$(6) \mbox{mmmmmm} \{2\}$$ separately?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out. Consider Example 1:

$$
\mbox{[gb]{1}(6)mmmmmm{2}(2)mm{3}(2)mm{4}(1)o{5}(1)m{6}(2)oo}. 
$$

$\mbox{{1}(6)mmmmmm}\;$ means you started out with 6 polynomials of degree 1 and you have to keep all 6 of them in the Groebner basis (gb).

$\mbox{{2}(2)mm}\;$ means you have 2 polynomials of degree 2 in your gb and you have to keep both polynomials in gb because of the two m's because they do not reduce to zero.

$\mbox{{3}(2)mm}\;$ means you have 2 polynomials of degree 3 and you have to keep both of them in your gb.

$\mbox{{4}(1)o}\;$ means you have 1 polynomial of degree 4 but o means it reduced to zero so you can get rid of it from your gb.

$\mbox{{5}(1)m}\;$ means you have 1 polynomial of degree 5 but you have to keep it in your gb.

$\mbox{{6}(2)oo}\;$ means you ahve 2 polynomials of degree 6 in your gb but they both reduce to zero so you can get rid of them.

Thus, we have $6+ 2+ 2+ 0+1+0 = 11$ $=$ total number of generators in gb. The reason why we are throwing away some of the polynomials is because Macaulay2 automatically produces a minimal Groebner basis. So it throws out extraneous basis elements.